# Star glowing shader graph

Tags: unity, shaders, graphic-effects, unity-shader-graph

How could I make a shader graph that makes spheres that look like on this image? I'm new to shaders and I don't know how to do this. Also, if it's possible I would like a property to change the glowing intensity

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I know this is old, but a few weeks ago we found a solution and I think it would help some people to post it here. Using the VFX graph and the HYG database, it is possible to render hundreds of thousands of stars without any large performance impact. it works by encoding the stars into a texture. The RGB represents the position relative to the earth, and the alpha is the magnitude. Then, the graph read the texture and generate 2D stars. I am not taking credits for this solution, Glurth made 99% of it. This is just a part of the system, but an experienced programmer will be able to easily make the script. [image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'd recommend keeping your previous answer visible too. Even if it wasn't right for your needs, it might help others. It's totally OK to have more than one answer to a question — the accepted checkmark lets you highlight the one you found the best for your needs.